# How can i use VALA delegates in GTK3 button callback?

Tags: delegates, gtk3, vala

I'm trying to understand Vala delegates with Gtk3.
I tested callback and lambda with no problem.
I wanna test a delegate callback, here my code :

```
using Gtk;

delegate void typeDelegate(Button button);

int main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);
    typeDelegate cb = cbLabelf;
    var window = new Window ();
    window.title = "First GTK+ Program";
    window.border_width = 10;
    window.window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER;
    window.set_default_size (350, 70);
    window.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);

    var button = new Button.with_label ("Click me!");

    //button.clicked.connect (cb);
    //button.clicked+= cb;   
    button.clicked.connect+=cb;

    window.add (button);
    window.show_all ();

    Gtk.main ();
    return 0;
}

void cbLabelf(Button button)
{
 button.label = "tank yu";   


 }
```

I also red generated C code ( when i use lambda) to understand.
Here the compil error : 
GTKsampleDelegate.vala:20.5-20.30: error: Arithmetic operation not supported for types `Gtk.Button.clicked.connect' and`typeDelegate'
    button.clicked.connect+=cb;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

Seems that you want to get the intrinsic variable that holds the instance that emitted the signal, I find strange that vala doesn't let you use a delegate variable to obtain it via parameter, yet, you can use one of the forms below: using no delegation variable (A) or bypassing the error with a closure (B).

```
public class FooSignalClass : Object {
    /* Gtk Button.clicked signal has the void f(void) signature */
    public signal void on_foo ();
    public void foo() {
        on_foo();
    }
}

public delegate void FooSignalFunc (FooSignalClass fooer);

void on_foo_handler (FooSignalClass fooer) {
    long fooer_memory_address = (long)fooer;
    GLib.message(@"fooer exists? $(fooer!=null).");
    GLib.message(@"address=$fooer_memory_address.");
}

int main () {

    var foo_signal = new FooSignalClass();
    long fooer_memory_address = (long)foo_signal;
    GLib.message(@"foo_signal address=$fooer_memory_address.");

    /* Option A: Connect directly without the delegate variable */
    foo_signal.on_foo.connect(on_foo_handler);

    /* Option B: You cant use a delegate directly, bypass it with a closure */
    FooSignalFunc func = on_foo_handler;
    foo_signal.on_foo.connect((instance) => {
        func(instance);
    });

    foo_signal.foo();

    return 0;
}
```